# Why does "flutter create ./" not seems to work

Tags: flutter

Is there any way to create flutter app in current directory/folder ?? ‍♂️

`flutter create ./` does not seems to work on git repo

Comment: "flutter create ." is the shortcut for "refresh the initial files here without removing any existing additions".  Not sure what "./".  Why do you not want flutter create to create a new empty project directory?

Comment: Navigate to your folder project and run flutter create . In cmd

Comment: it is working for me